# Internet Explorer 11 sometimes disables its "Back" button for no apparent reason

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Internet Explorer 11 sometimes disables its "Back" button for no apparent reason after clicking a link, some links later it re-enables it, and so on. See [screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqk82.gif).

The links do not use fancy javascript or strange redirects.
Add-Ons are disabled. All browser settings are set to defaults. Cache is empty.

What is the reason that Internet Explorer 11 disables the "Back" button?
How can I stop that behavior?

Comment: At first try to disable all add-ons and see if that solves the back button problem. If not reset the internet explorer..

Comment: @vembutech Thx. I edited my question for clarity, and I have written an answer with a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

**Analysis**

I haven't found out the root cause for this strange behavior yet, but it only shows under the following circumstances:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| User is member of local group ...      |    | Back button         |
| Users   | Power Users | Administrators |    | unexpected behavior |
|=========|=============|================|====|=====================|
| Yes     | Yes or No   | Yes            | => | No                  |
|---------|-------------|----------------|----|---------------------|
| Yes     | No          | No             | => | No                  |
|---------|-------------|----------------|----|---------------------|
| Yes     | Yes         | No             | => | Yes                 |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I didn't try other combinations of group memberships. So the unexpected behavior requires the user to be in group *Power Users* but not *Administrators*.

**Workaround**

Since [*Power Users* is a legacy group that is not really being used in Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771990.aspx), we removed users from *Power Users* (via Group Policy) which stopped the unexpected behavior.

See also this [thread from answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_update/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-for-x64-power/d6c93edc-ac94-47f4-89a7-6f9ba380a6aa?page=3).

Comment: that is quite bizarre

Comment: Yes, it is bizarre. :)